# Display none and block using html dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Display none and block using an html dropdown using JavaScript

```
function getval(sel) {
    if (document.getElementById("applicant").value = "2") {
        document.getElementById('li2').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('li3').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('li4').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('li5').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("applicant").value = "3") {
        document.getElementById('li2').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('li3').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('li4').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('li5').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("applicant").value = "4") {
        document.getElementById('li2').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('li3').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('li4').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('li5').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("applicant").value = "5") {
        document.getElementById('li2').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('li3').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('li4').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('li5').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Are you asking some of sort question why cant you be more clear and show us some markup using [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what the problem is (since you don't describe it), I'm guessing it (you're missing an `=`).

Change

```
if (document.getElementById("applicant").value = "..."
```

to

```
if (document.getElementById("applicant").value == "..."
```